# Change image without reload using php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, image-uploading

I am trying to write the code to let users upload their profile picture using php. I want the image to be updated without reloading the page. I have tried using ajax to do this.
My ajax code is:

```
  function f()
  {

    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

              x=document.getElementById("img");  //Find the element
             x.innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;  //Change the content

        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("POST", "Uploadimage.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(); 
}
```

Uploadimage.php is the file in which uploads the image and moves it into a folder.The $_FILES has the details of the file(filename,type etc...).
The above code is not working i.e., the image is not getting updated.Please help me how to correct this.
Thank you.

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Take a look at jQuery.

Comment: Is it not possible using ajax??

Comment: He's referring to jQuery ajax() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , jQuery is a JavaScript framework, it also provides much easier ways to perform ajax requests and handling response etc

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would only return the new url name of the profile pic and change the src of the profile pic upon success. Such as:

```
x = document.getElementById('img'); // If this is the <img> tag
x.src = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

Note that the url name of the new pic will need a new url, or else I don't think any browser will try to reload the pic, regardless of caching rules set by the server.